# JavaScript: Is there any performance benefit to stopping event propagation?

Tags: javascript, event-propagation

Is it considered 'good practice' to stop JavaScript event propagation - does it benefit performance in any way?

I'm wondering if there is benefit *outside* of layout purposes where you stop propagation so you don't trigger multiple events accidentially.

Comment: Even if it does, it's squarely within the realm of micro-optimization. It's nothing you would notice in normal use.

Comment: This does not explain the benefit of stopping event propagation, but it explains the price you have to pay for it: https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only when it is necessary to the program logic, such as to prevent form submission or another DOM element's action being triggered. Unless you have a seriously complex DOM tree, there will not be any serious performance hit.

Comment: This is no answer, because the text does neither define what a "seriously complex DOM tree" is nor what a "serious performance hit" is. The statement has no serious value.

Answer (score 6):

It entirely depends on the ***DOM complexity*** and the ***actions taken in each event*** that is triggered.

You would stop propagating events mainly not because of complexity but because of unwanted actions not to take place.

For example: Consider a situation where you have a show hide `div` and when you click on the `div` it should open and if you click anywhere else in the document it should close.

So you would wire an `onclick` event handler to the document as well as the `div`. So you have to stop propagating the event when clicked on the `div` so that the document click handler won't be invoked. That's a situation where you use stop event propagation.

Comment: You can use `preventDefault`, if you want that a parent element does not do what it normally would do.

Comment: This is no answer, because the text says nothing about the performance impact.